# Header: Logo to the left, nav to the right. (Vertical aligned to the center)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having trouble aligning my navigation to the right of the header. Searching on the web, I think the problem is because I'm aligned the items vertically to the center, and the float option isn't working with that.

Any clues?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/PabloArteeL/T7JDJ/

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="logowrapper" style="padding-left:1em;">
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <nav><a href="#">SOME LINK</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.logowrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/250x40");
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
}
nav {
    right: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Desired effect:

[image: Desired Effect]

Comment: Can you post an image of the desired effect? it makes it easier for us to know what you are asking.

Comment: Added to the Original Post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `<nav>`a width and change `text-align:left;` to `text-align:center;` or it will not center text:

```
nav {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width:400px;
}
```

Result:
[image]

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/T7JDJ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<header>
    <div class="logowrapper">
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "link">
    <nav><a href="#">SOME LINK</a>
    </nav>
    <div>
</header>
```

css :

```
 header {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.logowrapper {
    height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left:1em;
    float: left;
    padding: 18px;
}
.logo {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/250x40");
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
}

.link {
    padding: 30px;
}
nav {
    right: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
}
nav a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine's answer will only work if it is text. A better solution uses floats and margin. For general elements side by side it's best to use `display: block` over `display: table-cell` which emulates a `<td>`

http://jsfiddle.net/T7JDJ/8/

Just change the margins, and widths to your liking.

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to avoid hard-codding measures. The original approach is working with divs, not only text.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. Look at this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/T7JDJ/9/]. If I add an image, everything breaks. By break, I mean they're not inline anymore.

Comment: No assumptions there, I'm using it with divs. I also inserted images to your original fiddle and it broke too.